# Reinstalling bumblebee on Kernel 4.4

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I updated my kernel from 3.19 to 4.4, but afterwards the initialization of bumblebee failed. Therefore I removed it completely (purge) and reinstalled it, this time with the current nvidia driver (352) instead of the older one (331). But I still have the NVidia GPU running, and if I start optirun, I get

```
[ 1255.207756] [ERROR]The Bumblebee daemon has not been started yet or the socket path /var/run/bumblebee.socket was incorrect.
[ 1255.207776] [ERROR]Could not connect to bumblebee daemon - is it running?
```

If I check if the nvidia driver is loaded (with `lsmod | grep -E 'nvidia|nouveau'`), I get nothing in return. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Loadable kernel modules in Linux are loaded (and unloaded) by the modprobe command. They are located in `/lib/modules` and have had the extension .ko ("kernel object") since version 2.6 (previous versions used the .o extension). Often when you update your kernel and have compiled your own drivers in previous kernels you must compile them again. If binaries were obtained through pre-compiled such as deb Debian packages which are handled via dpkg through package managers such as apt/aptitude or  if your distribution is another flavor of Linux such as RHEL then BRPM's or RPM Package Manager sometimes known as RedHat Package Manager.

Depending on your distribution an attempt to load either drivers with "`modprobe [options] [-i] [-b] modulename`" or in your case "`modprobe nouveau`" | "`modprobe nvidia`" | "`modprobe nv`" if they exists and if they are located in the corresponding location for your distribution. Ubuntu is based off of Debian and it may be assumed packages are most likley handled through dpkg managers on your system if its what these forums are designated for.

If your problem still exists, perhaps shed more light on the issue by including these outputs:

```
/usr/bin/dmesg
/usr/bin/uname -a
```

If possible please include information on your kernel objects by attempting:

```
/usr/sbin/modinfo nvidia
/usr/sbin/modinfo bbswitch
```

Did you compile bumblebee & your NVIDIA driver from source or did you use a pre-compiled package? If they were compiled by you what versions did you use? If you installed the pre-compiled packages please provide the exact versions.